# I have two tables which contains duplicate values and unique values. I don't need duplicate values from both the tables, I need only unique values

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables which contains duplicate values and unique values I don't need duplicate values from both the tables I need only unique values and copy it into a new table as output.

For ex:

```
Table 1 data
col1
101
102
103
104
Table 2 data
col1
101
102
103
105
```

Output required is

```
New Table 3 data
col1
104
105
```

The query is

```
SELECT 
    Table 1 data.col1 
FROM 
    Table 1 data 
LEFT JOIN 
    Table 2 data 
ON 
    Table 1 data.col1 = Table 2 data.col1 
WHERE 
    Table 2 data.col1 is NULL
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Show some code

Comment: You can [merge](http://php.net/array_merge) the 2 arrays and get [unique](http://php.net/array_unique) values if you have a low number of records in each table.

Comment: Hi @BinarWeb, I have records of more than 3+ lakh rows

Comment: @Micheal please edit your question and insert that query

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help :

```
(SELECT t1.col1 FROM t1 left join t2 on t1.col1 =t2.col1 WHERE t2.col1 is null) union (SELECT t2.col1 FROM t2 left join t1 on t1.col1=t2.col1 WHERE t1.col1 is null)
```

Comment: @AmanAggarwal The query is still not giving any output "phpmyadmin" says "Loading" but it does not load any data.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Below Query with UNION:

```
(SELECT Table1.column1 FROM Table1 left join Table2 on Table1.column1 =Table2.column1 WHERE Table2.column1 is null) 
union
(SELECT Table2.column1 FROM Table2 left join Table1 on Table1.column1=Table2.column1 WHERE Table1.column1 is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

get the distinct value from both table (use UNION) to produce
101 102 103 104 105

then get the intersect data from both table (use INNER JOIN) to produce
101 102 103

after that, subtract result 2 from result 1 (in Oracle you can use MINUS operator, but you can use the same idea to build complex query for that in mysql using NOT IN operator)

Comment: Could you please help me in writing this query? I am new to SQL

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work. I tried in Oracle Database. hopefully It will work in MYSQL also.

```
    SELECT col1
        FROM tab1 outers
           WHERE NOT EXISTS
              (SELECT col1 FROM tab2 inners WHERE outers.COL1 = inners.COL1)        
    UNION
    SELECT col1
       FROM tab2 outers
           WHERE NOT EXISTS
               (SELECT col1 FROM tab1 inners WHERE outers.COL1 = inners.COL1);
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO Table 3 data (clo1) SELECT CombinedValue FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT col1 AS CombinedValue FROM Table 1 data UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM Table 2 data ) temp GROUP BY CombinedValue HAVING COUNT(*) =1

This query worked for me :)

Thank you all for your help